# I don't know how I do that

Tags: .htaccess, url, joomla, html

I have been trying to redirect my webpage from http://35.176.138.35/CSGO/ to http://www.csgoskins.es using .htaccess and don't know what I've done that I destroyed my page, you can see that by entering at my page, that is the URL, I don't know how I generated:

```
http://csgoskins.es/www/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.eswww/NOMHOME/es/c/s/g/csgoskins/www/htdocs/public/www.csgoskins.es
```

Solution: make a forced refresh of the page.

Comment: Please, is school work, I REALLY need helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^35\.176\.138\.35$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/CSGO
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://csgoskins.es [R=301]
```